# Is there a way to have 2 versions of an Angular component - read + write?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular dashboard web app, with two user types -- one with read views, and one with write/edit control. Otherwise, the pages are basically the exact same throughout the app. Is it possible to use the same page for each version with modifications other than a lot of ngIfs? Or do I just need to make near duplicate files for each component?

I'm new to the language, so any info would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can pass a flag, and depend on it you can make the controls readable or writeable.

Comment: That would involve a lot of ngIfs, no? Which is fine if that's the simplest solution, just don't want cluttered code if avoidable

Comment: No, it won't. The flag you pass is a boolean and you can use it to disable any input control.